# Timer don't show a month

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

As in title. I write a easy timer , which set time and date . Time works well , but date not.
It shows a year and a day , but not month . Why ?

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication_timer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int h = DateTime.Now.Hour;
            int m = DateTime.Now.Minute;
            int s = DateTime.Now.Minute;

            int d = DateTime.Now.Day;
            int y = DateTime.Now.Year;
            int t = DateTime.Now.Month;

            label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/tt/yy");

            label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Result of this code :

```
time eg : 11:34:23
date eg : 20--2013
```

result must change to :

```
time eg : 11:34:23
date eg : 20/01/2013
```

Could you help me how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `dd/MM/yy` not `dd/tt/yy`.

See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for more information.

I can also see you have the following line:

`int s = DateTime.Now.Minute;`

I assume you meant:

`int s = DateTime.Now.Second;`

EDIT:

In fact, I can't see any reason why you are saving any portions of the date/time in local variables as they aren't being used.

Answer (score 1):

Your `DateTime` formatting is wrong. Try with `dd/MM/yy` format like this;

```
label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy");
```

Check out [**`Custom Date and Time Format Strings`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for more date and time format informations.

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/zL8pOH).